# Count how many rows have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I write an SQL query to count the total number of a specific num value in the num column of a table?

Assuming we have the following data.

| NAME | NUM |
| --- | --- |
| SAM | 1 |
| BOB | 1 |
| JAKE | 2 |
| JOHN | 4 |

Take the following query:

```sql
SELECT WHERE num = 1;
```

This would return these two rows.

| NAME | NUM |
| --- | --- |
| SAM | 1 |
| BOB | 1 |

Comment: what motivates so many duplicate answers to such a simple but ill-posed question? sigh... must avoid looking into the sausage making process!

Answer (score 165):

Try

```
SELECT NAME, count(*) as NUM FROM tbl GROUP BY NAME
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe41cd/2)**

Comment: If it's necessary to filter out also by specific count number, let's say get only less than 10 or more then 25, you can use `HAVING` operator, 
like
`GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) > ...`

Answer (score 19):

If you want to have the result for all values of `NUM`:

```
SELECT `NUM`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `NUM`
```

Or just for one specific:

```
SELECT `NUM`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM yourTable
WHERE `NUM`=1
```

Answer (score 16):

FOR SPECIFIC NUM:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE NUM = 1
```

FOR ALL NUM:

```
SELECT NUM, COUNT(1) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY NUM
```

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(NUM) as 'result' 
FROM 
   Table1 
GROUP BY 
   NUM 
HAVING NUM = 1
```

Comment: @necromancer please explain, why is having needed here? it makes no sense to use having in this context. If he was using it for comparing the  aggregate, then it was upvote worthy.

Comment: @NickN. `having num = 1` is equivalent to `where num = `, so it is not wrong and it is not "makes no sense". I thought it was refreshingly different to do it this way rather than the more conventional `where`. The equivalence is not obvious at first sight, so I'd encourage trying it out yourself.

Comment: @necromancer I still don't see it, since `where` is the same, why use `having`?

Comment: @NickN. `having` is for group-level criteria; `where` is for row-level criteria. They cannot be interchanged in general. In this special boundary case however, they can be interchanged. Therefore the output is the same. But, philosophically I think of `NUM` as a group-level criteria since the group by is done on `NUM` itself. Therefore I appreciate `having` instead of `where`. You will probably not appreciate my abstract concern in favor of some other concern, but just explaining it so you don't think I'm totally crazy.

Comment: @necromancer, thanks for putting detail explanation. It makes lot of sense now. Thanks for a good discussion!

Answer (score 6):

Try this Query

```
select NUM, count(1) as count 
from tbl 
where num = 1
group by NUM
--having count(1) (You condition)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c2ff/4)**

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(num) WHERE num = 1;
```

Comment: No sir, afaik he wants the sum of the values not the number occurrence.

Comment: hey, you are right!  dude there is one single correct answer, this one!

Comment: @randomstring It's completely incorrect Query. **`1.`** What if OP want **`where num=2`**. **`2`** Besides this query is gonna return **`error`**, as it doesn't specifies the **`tablename`**.

Comment: @Luv, you are right but OP didn't give a table name in the first place so i intended this as a pseudo query nothing more.

Comment: @0xAli Then too, its a wrong answer, we can't use **`sum()`** instead of **`count()`**. Please refer this **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c2ff/6)**

Comment: It's functioning as intended, `result: 2` is '1'+'1' as the two values of the returned rows not the count of them i am well aware of that, but i think that's what the OP wanted to do.. i could be wrong. but thanks for trying to correct me - always appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT SUM(IF(your_column=3,1,0)) FROM your_table WHERE your_where_contion='something';`

e.g. for you query:-

`SELECT SUM(IF(num=1,1,0)) FROM your_table_name;`

Answer (score -3):

Use this query this will give your output:

```
select 
  t.name
  ,( select 
       count (*) as num_value 
     from Table 
      where num =t.num) cnt 
from Table t;
```